How to get the terminal output of a program over a pipe, in real time?
I'm writing a graphical interface for a CLI application. For this purpose, I'd like to get its terminal output through a pipe in real time.
The issue is that while the content of the pipe is close enough to the terminal output, it only arrives in big chunks; sometimes, the entire output of the program arrives only when it terminates. When executing the program in a terminal, the output arrives in real time instead.
The "chunked" behavior occurred across different consumers (Python subprocess.Popen with varying configurations, redirect to a file and display with tail, pipe to cat), so it's unlikely to be an issue with a specific consumer.
Why does this chunking occur? Is there a way to flush the buffer of the application from Python? Is there some windows or python tool that emulates a terminal to the program and then pushes the output through a pipe?

See if this answer works for you, using winpty (last updated 2017) and let me know.

@harrymc it crashes with an "msys-2.0.dll not found" error (the mvsc version doesn't contain a winpty.exe). After downloading a random msys-2.0.dll, it works, but the "real" msys2 is far too large to distribute (apparently 300MB on disk), and I'd worry about security or license issues distributing the dll alone. Is there perhaps some python library that can do the same?
